# Align buttons, text, and Divs in mass

Tags: javascript, css, html, alignment

I want to align everything in a big part of code to the right. So it looks better and does not distract from the other parts. So it is one the right side and still clickable with the rest of the code. Just in the gui it is aligned to the right. This is the code i want to put to the right of the screen. Sorry if I am a noob for not knowing this and knowing how to make correct code in stack overflow.

```
    <p>================================</p>
<button style="background-color:Purple; color:red; border:red; font-size:15px;" type="button"
onclick="buyMom()">Buy 1 mom</button>
<p>Moms:+1 animals per second</p>
<div id="momCount">0</div>
<div id="momPrice">50</div><br>
<p>================================</p>
<button style="background-color:red; color:purple; border:red; font-size:15px;" type="button"
onclick="buyFarm()">Buy 1 farm</button>
<p>Farms:+50 animals per second</p>
 <div id="farmCount">0</div>
<div id="farmPrice">500</div><br>
<p>================================</p>
<button style="background-color:yellow; color:blue; border:red; font-size:15px;" type="button"
onclick="buyFactory()">Buy 1 factory</button>
<p>Factorys:+100 animals per second</p>
<div id="factoryCount">0</div>
<div id="factoryPrice">1000</div><br>
<p>================================</p>    
 <button style="background-color:orange; color:red; border:red; font-size:15px;" type="button"
onclick="buyClone()">Buy 1 cloner</button>
<p>Cloners:+200 animals per second</p>
<div id="cloneCount">0</div>
<div id="clonePrice">2000</div><br>
 <p>================================</p>
```

Comment: Okay...what's the question? What problem are you having?

Answer (score 1):

Just give it a CSS `text-align:right;` and wrap the html part in a selector you can target via css.

HTML

```
<div class="container">
<p>================================</p>
<button style="background-color:Purple; color:red; border:red; font-size:15px;" type="button"
onclick="buyMom()">Buy 1 mom</button>
<p>Moms:+1 animals per second</p>
<div id="momCount">0</div>
<div id="momPrice">50</div><br>
<p>================================</p>
<button style="background-color:red; color:purple; border:red; font-size:15px;" type="button"
onclick="buyFarm()">Buy 1 farm</button>
<p>Farms:+50 animals per second</p>
 <div id="farmCount">0</div>
<div id="farmPrice">500</div><br>
<p>================================</p>
<button style="background-color:yellow; color:blue; border:red; font-size:15px;" type="button"
onclick="buyFactory()">Buy 1 factory</button>
<p>Factorys:+100 animals per second</p>
<div id="factoryCount">0</div>
<div id="factoryPrice">1000</div><br>
<p>================================</p>    
 <button style="background-color:orange; color:red; border:red; font-size:15px;" type="button"
onclick="buyClone()">Buy 1 cloner</button>
<p>Cloners:+200 animals per second</p>
<div id="cloneCount">0</div>
<div id="clonePrice">2000</div><br>
<p>================================</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
    text-align: right;
}
```

**[example FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mdEuj/)**

Comment: How can i align in to upper right so it is next to the picture? Here is what it looks like http://jsfiddle.net/blosche/nHPMx/9/ I want the things to be up in the right at the very top along next to the picture.

Comment: Just give it a `float: right`and wrap the image elements in a container as well and give them a `float: left`. Here is your updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nHPMx/12/. If my answer is to your satisfaction and solved your question, please upvote it and accept it by clicking the check mark.

Comment: Why does it not go all the way to the top when I edited the original? I want the animals - animals per second in center and everything you can buy upper right. http://jsfiddle.net/blosche/nHPMx/13/